# Can't mount Ubuntu iso to hardrive partition

Tags: linux, ubuntu, dual-boot, uefi

I've been trying to dual boot my new laptop (Dell XPS 15 9560) with Windows and Ubuntu. I've done this process before on my Lenovo with no issues using the process outlined in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JvBZBfY5Pfc) so I tried to use the same process with my dell laptop.

I first partitioned my hardrive by deallocating 30 GB from to be used by Linux. I then changed the boot sequence to boot from the USB first. When booting from the USB, in the GRUB menu, I first chose the option to install Ubuntu. I went through the step to choose the language, setup the wi-fi connection, and install third party software, but when I get to the step to choose the installation type, there are no devices being displayed.

I made sure that all drivers on the laptop were installed and ran system diagnostics to ensure that nothing was wrong with the hardware. I'm not sure what the issue is because when I did the same process on my Lenovo, all of the partitions showed up in this menu. **What could be causing the problem?**

The image of the installation type screen is below:

[image]

Comment: Maybe partition scheme of the USB is not `GPT for UEFI`. Use [rufus](https://rufus.akeo.ie/) (Windows) to make a bootable USB.

Comment: I did use rufus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely problems in the BIOS with the configuration of SATA (in BIOS, by default, most likely, SATA - RAID enabled). Here it is described in detail - https://github.com/rcasero/doc/wiki/Ubuntu-linux-on-Dell-XPS-15-(9560)#installation-steps and https://askubuntu.com/a/912430/766791

It is probably difficult to describe in more detail.
Although, as said in the commentary, try the Rufus - it will be more correct.

Comment: Yes, I used rufus. And you were correct, SATA was enabled and the setting needed to be switched to AHCI.